# android dialog wont close after opening system location settings

Tags: android, dialog, settings

I have a dialog that prompts users to enable gps location if it's not enabled.

After opening the settings, and the user enableing gps, and pressing the back button from the location settings screen they come back to the app, but the dialog is still visible.

Here is the code for the button clicked.

```
    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
```

My question is why does the dialog.dismiss() not close the dialog, I have also tried dialog.cancel() with same result.  Is there something I should be doing after opening the settings screen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly this code in my `Activity`:

```
private void showLocationDisabledInfo() {
    final Context c = this;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    builder.setMessage("TEST");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            c.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

and it does close the dialog automatically, no matter what button I click. It's from my application, and it was tested on devices with APIs `8` and `10`, and emulator running API `17`. The only difference (possibly) between our codes is the value of `mContext`. Please provide the whole code responsible for setting up the dialog and the environment in which you've seen described behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have borrowed some code from a web tutorial, and it set the context like so: private final Context mContext; and then set it a few lines later.

removing the 'final' solved the issue.

I am new to java, how does that work?  I would expect the setting to cause and error if it was already defined as a final?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Final fields must be set on declaration or in class constructor. Setting them anywhere else or re-setting them causes a compile-time error. Final local variables must be set on declaration and can't be re-set. But be careful - if someone stated `mContext` as `final`, maybe he did it for a reason ;)